# How to use ItemAnimator in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I want to do animation when an item is added or removed from adapter of recyclerview. I'am trying to use RecyclerView.ItemAnimator as follows but it is not working..

```
    public class MyAnimator extends RecyclerView.ItemAnimator{

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(ViewHolder arg0) {
        Log.d("test","Added Animation");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(ViewHolder arg0, ViewHolder arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
        Log.d("test","Change Animation");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateMove(ViewHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(ViewHolder arg0) {
        Log.d("test", "Remove Animation");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimation(ViewHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void runPendingAnimations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I'am using above code as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    data=new ArrayList<String>();   


    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    animator = new MyAnimator();
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);            

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(data);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 

}
```

Whenever i add a new item into dataset and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` i expected the Log present in `animateAdd(ViewHolder arg0)` present in  MyAnimator class; but it's not coming..am i missing something..Why its not working.

Answer (score 30):

First of all, you don't need custom ItemAnimator for that. You can use default one, remove `mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);`

Also, you have to use `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyItemRemoved()` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it invokes proper animation for you.

Comment: how to create custom ItemAnimator?

Comment: @KishanVaghela You should extend the DefaultItemAnimator class!