# Stop animation after recyclerview inflates screen

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a special animation that populates the cards for my `RecyclerView`.  The animation works good (at least for inflating).  I don't want this animation to be used after initial inflation.  In other words, I don't want any animation for scrolling (or really any action by the user after initial inflation of enough cards to fill the user's screen).  I can't figure out how to grab the position number -or- turn off animation after populating -or- any way to do this.  My animation is called in the adapter.  Here's the adapter code that I am using to set the animation.

```
public class TagAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<TagDataModel> dataSet;
private Context context;

public TagAdapter (ArrayList<TagDataModel> ds, Context ctx){
    this.dataSet =ds;
    this.context =ctx;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_tag;
    ArrayList<TagDataModel> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    CardView card;

    ViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, ArrayList<TagDataModel> ds) {
        super(itemView);
        this.dataSet = ds;
        this.context =ctx;
        this.tv_tag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTag);
        this.card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_tag);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_tag, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view, context, dataSet);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    final int activePosition = context.getSharedPreferences("userPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("np_tag", 0);
    TextView tv_tag = holder.tv_tag;
    CardView card = holder.card;
    tv_tag.setText(dataSet.get(position).getTag());

    });
    animate(holder.itemView, position);  //animate only first page UPDATE
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}

private void animate(View view, final int pos) {
    view.animate().cancel();
    view.setTranslationY(100);
    view.setAlpha(0);
    view.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(0).setDuration(300).setStartDelay(pos *100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your current animation from bindViewHolder and 
use custom  ItemAnimator and override animateAdd method.
You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831083/how-to-use-itemanimator-in-a-recyclerview)

This should give you the desired result.

```
public class MyItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {

 @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        animate(viewHolder.itemView);
        return true;
    }

private void animate(View view) {
    view.setTranslationY(100);
    view.setAlpha(0);
    view.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(0).setDuration(300);
}


}
```

Now set this item animator to your recyclerview.

recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyItemAnimator());

Try this :)

Comment: I believe this link tells me how to end animation.  I can do that,  but I need to know how to end animation *after inflation*.  This is the tricky part for me.

Comment: It will animate only on inflation and not after that.

Comment: Thanks, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provide the code of `Activity` where you use this `RecyclerView`. Anyhow, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30410605/2788613) will be helpful for you to detect whether your `RecyclerView` has reached the last item or not. 
And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854673/2788613) will help you to detect whether your layout is completely created/inflated.

Comment: I do not want to target last item,  I want to target RecyclerView has *finished inflating*.  This will be a much smaller number.

Comment: Your requirement is to start animation when `RecyclerView` starts being created/inflated and stop animation when it is done. Am I right? 
In order to properly understand what you're currently doing with `RecyclerView`, you'll also have to provide the code where you're using this recyclerView (i.e your `Activity`)

Comment: Anyhow, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854673/2788613) might still help. This contains a listener that is called when layout is completely loaded/inflated.