# how to Use RecyclerView.ItemAnimator With RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in Android Development. When I search for RecyclerView animation, I have found about RecyclerView.ItemAnimator and but I can't find any tutorial on how to use this. I have read this [How to use ItemAnimator in a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831083/how-to-use-itemanimator-in-a-recyclerview). But still, I don't get anything.

I have found documentation.

**By default, RecyclerView uses DefaultItemAnimator.**

What type of animation can expect from DefaultItemAnimator If I use RecyclerView?

I have used LayoutAnimation, When should I use RecyclerView.ItemAnimator?

Comment: The default item animator works when updating your `RecycleView`. Let's say when you delete, add or update. For eg., the animation in Gmail or Messages when you delete.

Comment: If I have a static list, It doesn't work?

Comment: You can put it to effect when you load the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am weak in English too. could you please give me more information. What you mean by that?

Comment: Alright. A simple yet visually understanding way would be to refer this library https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators. This is how an item animator works.

Comment: I have seen most of the site use DefaultItemAnimator like this recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());, If it is default, then why they need to implement like this?

Comment: Let's call it an additional functionality to default one! :)

Comment: what you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Any**  type of animation to animate your recycler view item

[image]

Required steps to build the following behavior

1. Start off by creating the file `item_animation_fall_down.xml` in `res/anim/` and add the following:

   ```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_medium">

       <translate
           android:fromYDelta="-20%"
           android:toYDelta="0"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           />

       <alpha
           android:fromAlpha="0"
           android:toAlpha="1"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           />

       <scale
           android:fromXScale="105%"
           android:fromYScale="105%"
           android:toXScale="100%"
           android:toYScale="100%"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           />

   </set>
   ```
2. Defining the LayoutAnimation

With the item animation done it’s time to define the layout animation which will apply the item animation to each child in the layout. Create a new file called `layout_animation_fall_down.xml` in `res/anim/` and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:delay="15%"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    />
```

3. Applying the LayoutAnimation

A LayoutAnimation can be applied both programmatically and in XML.

**JAVA**

```
int resId = R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down;
LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ctx, resId);
recyclerview.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                        
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
    />
```

For more info visit [here](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213)

Comment: then what is the use of ItemAnimator? When should I use ?

Comment: You can use ItemAnimator to apply default animation or create a class then extend ItemAnimator and apply your desired animation, after all, set created class as a default animation

Answer (score 0):

You wish to animate rows of recyclerview. Use below function

```
 public void setFadeAnimation(View view) {
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Now Go to Adapter class and call this function like this inside onBindViewHolder method

```
setFadeAnimation(myViewHolder.itemView);
```

It will animate your rows

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to know what is the use of ItemAnimator? When should I use?