# How to remove GridLayout span count change animation in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-gridlayout

I have a RecyclerView and related Adapter class. And I changed the GridLayoutManager's span count.

```kotlin
    fun switchLayout() {
        if (layoutManager?.spanCount == 1) {
            layoutManager.spanCount = 5
        } else {
            layoutManager?.spanCount = 1
        }

        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)
    }
```

And then some animation comes up like below

[image]

It's interesting but I don't need it. So, How can I remove this animation?

Comment: Have you tried with: `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` just use `notifyDataSetChanged()` - first one is causing animations, second one will force-redraw whole grid from scratch (without respecting previous positions of items, thus moving animations)

for disabling all animations (for adding new item, removing, changing positions/order of 2 or more) you can use `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)` (like comment under question pointing out). then you can still use all `notifyItem...` methods, changes won't be animated.

or you can also define own custom `ItemAnimator` with disabled some of animations. e.g. in your case: `animateChange` should contain line `dispatchAnimationFinished(viewHolder)` and then `return false`. in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831083/how-to-use-itemanimator-in-a-recyclerview) some nice template to use. your class may `extends` [`DefaultItemAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DefaultItemAnimator) and then you may override only methods/animations which you want to disable/change